# How to copy some content in a system clipboard not a kill ring with elisp/emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, buffer, clipboard

I learned that copy something to kill buffer, I can use the kill-new buffer

```
(kill-new (file-truename buffer-file-name))
```

How about copying the content to clipboard? Does emacs/elisp provide the function?

### ADDED

I got 2 answers, but the answer seems to apply X windows system. As I use Aquamacs, it may not be a universal solution that can be applied to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(x-set-selection nil (file-truename buffer-file-name))
```

[Documentation for x-set-selection](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-System-Selections.html) says:

> This function sets a “selection” in
>   the X server. It takes two arguments:
>   a selection type type, and the value
>   to assign to it, data. If data is nil,
>   it means to clear out the selection.
>   Otherwise, data may be a string, a
>   symbol, an integer (or a cons of two
>   integers or list of two integers), an
>   overlay, or a cons of two markers
>   pointing to the same buffer. An
>   overlay or a pair of markers stands
>   for text in the overlay or between the
>   markers.
>
> The argument data may also be a vector
>   of valid non-vector selection values.
>
> Each possible type has its own
>   selection value, which changes
>   independently. The usual values of
>   type are PRIMARY, SECONDARY and
>   CLIPBOARD; these are symbols with
>   upper-case names, in accord with X
>   Window System conventions. If type is
>   nil, that stands for PRIMARY.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Emacs to automatically copy to the system clipboard as well as to the kill ring. The function `kill-new` calls `interprogram-cut-function`, which typically copies to a system clipboard if there is one. Under X Window, the variable `x-select-enable-clipboard` controls whether the primary selection or the clipboard is used.

Comment: I'm using Aquamacs on Mac. What would be the code to test if the tip works? Putting (x-select-enable-clipboard 1) in .emacs?

Comment: It's a variable, so `(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)`. Or better (although it doesn't matter in this particular case), since it's a customization option, set it through the Customize interface. But I don't think it exists in Aquamacs, since that's not running under X.